# Add record to SQL Server table with identity column using AngularJS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app using AlgularJS and connecting to a SQL Server 2008 database. I have these two tables:

MODEL

```
model_id int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
model_desc nvarchar(200)
```

MODEL_SPEC

```
model_spec_id int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
model_id int not null,
model_spec_desc nvarchar(200)
```

In my app, when adding a new model, I have a list of specs on the same page. In order to save the specs, I need to save the model first. How do I get the `model_id` once the model record is inserted into the model table?

My existing function in .net looks like this (which obviously isn't returning the `model_id`):

```
 public int CreateModel(model mdl)
 {
        bool result = true;

        _context.models.Add(mdl);
        result = _context.SaveChanges() > 0;

        if (result)
        {
            return mdl.model_id;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Below is my Angular function for posting the request to create the model:

```
this.addModel = function (mdl) {
    var userObj = { "model_id": mdl.model_id, "model_desc": mdl.model_desc }
    return $http({
            url: '/models/CreateModel/',
            method: "POST",
            data: userObj
        });
    };
```

Comment: What is the `model_id` of `mdl` immediately after the `_context.SaveChanges()` but before the function returns?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  Via the debugger, what are the values in your `CreateModel` action?  If the `model_id` is available there, then you need to update `CreateModel` to return that instead of a `bool`.

Comment: I've updated the CreateModel function to return the model_id, as it is there once changes are saved. However, I'm unsure how this is accessed in my Angular function.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http.  Specifically, `$http.post('/models/CreateModel', userObj).then(function (res) { //res will contain your id }, function (err) { //this is called if there is an error });`

Answer (score 0):

You can return a JsonResult that contains the model id from your controller. It might look something like this:

```
public class ModelController : Controller
{
    private readonly IModelRepository _modelRepository;

    public ModelController(IModelRepository modelRepository)
    {
        _modelRepository = modelRepository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Model mdl)
    {
        var modelId = _modelRepository.CreateModel(mdl);

        return Json(modelId);
    }
}
```

You can then access the result from your angular code by doing something like this:

```
this.addModel(model).then(function(result){
    $scope.modelId = result;
})
```